# when i tried show 2 image together using opencv

Tags: opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np,sys

img1 = cv2.imread('Pictures/orange.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('pictures/orange.jpg')

cv2.imshow('apple', img1)
cv2.imshow('orange', img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when i try to run this code.

---

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      6 
      7 cv2.imshow('apple', img1)
----> 8 cv2.imshow('orange', img2)
      9 cv2.waitKey(0)
     10 

error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

i am getting this error.

Comment: Chances are pretty good that img2 is never loaded correctly. imread does not throw exceptions. You're supposed to look at retval to know if the image loaded correctly. Or you can initialize img2 with img2 = None. Then before imshow, do if img2 is not None:

Comment: Make sure p is in upper case for pictures